# How to detect if a windows app is Tablet PC "Aware"

Tags: windows, tablet-pc

Does anyone know how I can determine if an application is able to accept Tablet PC input? i.e. some kind of hittest or windows message that I can send it?

thanks,
H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tablet PC Input Panel (which as of Vista is available even on non-tablets other than the basic editions) will send input using the [Text Services Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms629032.aspx) (TSF) to an application that supports it. Otherwise it will send normal input messages to the application which basically means a bunch of simulated keyboard events.

I suspect you are trying to determine whether or not an application supports TSF which provides a much more integrated experience such as bidirectional correction interface, information about the current selection, context hints, etc.

I don't know if this is reliable but if the control in question is a rich edit, you could try the [EM_GETEDITSTYLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb788031.aspx) message which has a SES_USECTF flag in the return value that indicates whether or not TSF is turned on for that control. But for standard edit controls I'm not so sure. [This article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc187238.aspx) goes into much more detail about using the text services framework and is probably more than you care to implement.

Comment: Note that the article focuses on Vista's voice dictation capabilities but the Tablet PC input system uses the same architecture (and fallback mechanism) to send text to applications.